# Is there a way to have, in Fortran, some part of the output file name as the value of some variable used in my code?

Tags: io, fortran, fortran90

Using Fortran, I'd like to have parts of my output files names with the values of some variables used in the code.

```
 open(unit=3,file='out')
```

So I have my out when the program finish to run. I have a variable called `N` its value is read from a input file. Let's say the value is e.g. 0.5
Then what I'd like to have as the name of my output file is directly `out0.5`.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt you're right! The question you pointed out answered my question. Do you what should do? I mean, should I remove my question?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it, but you do not need to. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/is-there-any-value-to-not-deleting-my-own-duplicate-question  It will be probably put on hold as duplicate anyway.